# Nodejs - sequelize hasMany eager loading

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize latest version,and simply i need to eager load the model "VenueAddress" when finding a "Venue" model, but i get the below error:

i appreciate your help.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
at Object.module.exports.removeTicks (d:\GitProjects\bashed\node_modules\sequelize\lib\utils.js:595:13)
at Object.module.exports.addTicks
```

//find method:

```
db.Venue.find({ where: {venueId: id},include: [{model: db.VenueAddress}]}).then(function(venue){
if(!venue) {
return next(new Error('Failed to load venue ' + id));
} else {
req.venue = venue;
return next();
}
}).catch(function(err){
return next(err);
});
```

//models

```
Venue.hasMany(models.VenueAddress, {through: models.VenueAddress,foreignKey: 'venueId'});

VenueAddress.belongsTo(models.Venue, {through: models.VenueAddress,foreignKey: 'venueId'});
```

Comment: Could you check that `db.VenueAddress` is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to below link:
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3331#issuecomment-80886227

> mickhansen said: Looks like you need to remove the through property
>   from your Venue.hasMany association since it's not a N:M association.